# onBlur is not taking my input in Mui tags?

Tags: material-ui

I am using [MUI tags](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-mendeleev-wsidgr?file=/demo.tsx).
It is by default accept tags if we press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. But I want to achieve the same functionality if we `focus-out` from input.
I have written code for `onBlur` :

```
 // added by me --start
  const tagsBlurHandler = (e) => {
    const currentInputValue = e.target.value.trim();
    if (currentInputValue.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
  };
  // added by me --end

<TextField
{...params}
variant="filled"
label="freeSolo"
placeholder="Favorites"
onBlur={tagsBlurHandler} // added by me
/>
```

You can also see it live :  https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-mendeleev-wsidgr?file=/demo.tsx
When we write something in input box and focus-out it is NOT working as I expected. It should work same like when we press `Enter` key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Chip from "@mui/material/Chip";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";

export default function Tags() {
  // added by me --start
  const [value, setValue] = useState(["dfdf"]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const tagsBlurHandler = (e) => {
    debugger;
    const currentInputValue = e.target.value.trim();
    if (!currentInputValue || value.indexOf(currentInputValue) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    setValue([...value, currentInputValue]);
    setInputValue("");
  };
  // added by me --end

  return (
    <Stack spacing={3} sx={{ width: 500 }}>
      <Autocomplete
        onChange={(e, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        value={value}
        multiple
        id="tags-filled"
        options={top100Films.map((option) => option.title)}
        defaultValue={[top100Films[13].title]}
        freeSolo
        renderTags={(value: readonly string[], getTagProps) =>
          value.map((option: string, index: number) => (
            <Chip
              variant="outlined"
              label={option}
              {...getTagProps({ index })}
            />
          ))
        }
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
            {...params}
            variant="filled"
            label="freeSolo"
            placeholder="Favorites"
            onBlur={tagsBlurHandler}
          />
        )}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  {
    title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King",
    year: 2003
  },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  {
    title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring",
    year: 2001
  },
  {
    title: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
    year: 1980
  },
  { title: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  {
    title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers",
    year: 2002
  },
  { title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { title: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { title: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { title: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  {
    title: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
    year: 1977
  },
  { title: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { title: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { title: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { title: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { title: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { title: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { title: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Interstellar", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Casablanca", year: 1942 },
  { title: "City Lights", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Psycho", year: 1960 },
  { title: "The Green Mile", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Intouchables", year: 2011 },
  { title: "Modern Times", year: 1936 },
  { title: "Raiders of the Lost Ark", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Rear Window", year: 1954 },
  { title: "The Pianist", year: 2002 },
  { title: "The Departed", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Terminator 2: Judgment Day", year: 1991 },
  { title: "Back to the Future", year: 1985 },
  { title: "Whiplash", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Gladiator", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Memento", year: 2000 },
  { title: "The Prestige", year: 2006 },
  { title: "The Lion King", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Apocalypse Now", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Alien", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Sunset Boulevard", year: 1950 },
  {
    title:
      "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb",
    year: 1964
  },
  { title: "The Great Dictator", year: 1940 },
  { title: "Cinema Paradiso", year: 1988 },
  { title: "The Lives of Others", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Grave of the Fireflies", year: 1988 },
  { title: "Paths of Glory", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Django Unchained", year: 2012 },
  { title: "The Shining", year: 1980 },
  { title: "WALL·E", year: 2008 },
  { title: "American Beauty", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight Rises", year: 2012 },
  { title: "Princess Mononoke", year: 1997 },
  { title: "Aliens", year: 1986 },
  { title: "Oldboy", year: 2003 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in America", year: 1984 },
  { title: "Witness for the Prosecution", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Das Boot", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Citizen Kane", year: 1941 },
  { title: "North by Northwest", year: 1959 },
  { title: "Vertigo", year: 1958 },
  {
    title: "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi",
    year: 1983
  },
  { title: "Reservoir Dogs", year: 1992 },
  { title: "Braveheart", year: 1995 },
  { title: "M", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Requiem for a Dream", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Amélie", year: 2001 },
  { title: "A Clockwork Orange", year: 1971 },
  { title: "Like Stars on Earth", year: 2007 },
  { title: "Taxi Driver", year: 1976 },
  { title: "Lawrence of Arabia", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Double Indemnity", year: 1944 },
  {
    title: "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind",
    year: 2004
  },
  { title: "Amadeus", year: 1984 },
  { title: "To Kill a Mockingbird", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Toy Story 3", year: 2010 },
  { title: "Logan", year: 2017 },
  { title: "Full Metal Jacket", year: 1987 },
  { title: "Dangal", year: 2016 },
  { title: "The Sting", year: 1973 },
  { title: "2001: A Space Odyssey", year: 1968 },
  { title: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
  { title: "Toy Story", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Bicycle Thieves", year: 1948 },
  { title: "The Kid", year: 1921 },
  { title: "Inglourious Basterds", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Snatch", year: 2000 },
  { title: "3 Idiots", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail", year: 1975 }
];
```

You can use it like this

Comment: If we write `newtag` in input and then focus-out from input. It will do as what I wanted to achieve but after focus-out it will also leave the previous inserted tags to the `input`.

Comment: To remove previous inserted tag from input, we have to pass `clearOnBlur` property to `<Autocomplete clearOnBlur `